# How do I find the exponent, if there is an another unknown in the equation?

Tags: exponential-function

How do I solve for n?

$125 = x * 2^n$

This is what I have so far:

$5^3 = x * 2^n$

I do remember that according to the exponential rules,
that the powers should be the same if the equation is like this:

$8 = 2^n$

$2^3 = 2^n \iff 2^3 = 2^3$

I am not sure if this rule can be used in the equation above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which values can $x$ take? Can it be an arbritrary real number? Does it have to be an integer?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve for $n$, unless you want your answer to be in terms of $x$. In that case, $125/x=2^n$ tells you $n=\log_2(125/x)=3\log_2(5)-\log_2(x)$.

The reason it's not possible to solve for $n$ is because, no matter what $n$ you choose, there's always an appropriate choice of $x$ so that the equation is satisfied. (Why? Can you find an expression for such an $x$?) On the other hand, if $x$ is restricted to an **integer**, then you want to consider prime factorizations of both sides. I'll leave this to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We get $$\frac{125}{x}=2^n$$ so $$\ln\left(\frac{125}{x}\right)=n\ln(2)$$

Comment: You have two unknowns in your equation $$n$$ and $$x$$